# Varieties cannot be isomorphic to proper open subsets

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an irreducible variety and let $U \subset X$ be a proper open set.  Question : can there be a morphism $f : X \rightarrow U$ such that the composition $U \hookrightarrow X \stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} U$ is the identity?

My guess is that the answer is "no", but I can't seem to prove it.

One observation is that if $f$ exists, then it would give a procedure for taking a regular function $\phi : U \rightarrow k$ and extending it to all of $X$.  But this can definitely be done in some cases; for instance, if $X = \mathbb{A}^2$ and $U = \mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$.

Comment: The title seems to ask a different question than the body. The question in the body asks whether a proper open subset can be a retract. 

Comment: The question in the title is much more interesting than the question in the question.  For the question in the question, regard $f$ as a function from $X$ to $X$, and observe that $f$ restricts to the identity on $U$.  Thus $f$ must be the identity on the closure of $U$, which is all of $X$ since $X$ is irreducible.

Comment: The retraction question is slightly more subtle than it appears since the Zariski topology is not Hausdorff. One needs to use that varieties are separated. 

Answer (score 20, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ax-Grothendieck_theorem